# How to get file's itself directory without filename?

Tags: c++, console-application

I'm trying to get filename (directory) of file and make its subdirectory. But if my file's extension is .exe I would like to delete 8 characters to fully delete "test.exe" text in installer and then join //test (_tcscat(installer, _T("\test"));) Is it possible? Maybe it's possible to get folder name of that path without filename?

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        TCHAR buf0[MAX_PATH];
        GetModuleFileName(0, buf0, MAX_PATH);

        TCHAR installer[_MAX_PATH];
        _tcscpy(installer, buf0);
        _tcscat(installer, _T("\\test"));
        _mkdir(installer);
    }
```

edited:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{

    TCHAR buf0[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(0, buf0, MAX_PATH);
    boost::filesystem::path p(buf0);
    boost::filesystem::path dir = p.parent_path();
    TCHAR installer[_MAX_PATH];
    _tcscpy(installer, dir);
    _tcscat(installer, _T("\\test"));
    _mkdir(installer);


}

1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication6, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  ConsoleApplication6.cpp
1>ConsoleApplication6.cpp(107): error C2664: 'char *strcpy(char *,const char *)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'boost::filesystem::path' to 'const char *'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{

    TCHAR buf0[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(0, buf0, MAX_PATH);
    boost::filesystem::path p(buf0);
    boost::filesystem::path dir = p.parent_path() / boost::filesystem::path("test");
    //boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir);
    char * dir0 = dir;
    char installer[_MAX_PATH];
    _tcscpy(installer, dir0);
    _tcscat(installer, _T("\\test"));


}

1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication6, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  ConsoleApplication6.cpp
1>ConsoleApplication6.cpp(107): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'boost::filesystem::path' to 'char *'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: If possible, use `std::filesystem::path` (a C++17 library feature) or `boost::filesystem::path` instead of doing this manually.

Comment: @aschepler I edited my code but I'm getting error, how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using boost filesystem:

```
TCHAR buf0[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(0, buf0, MAX_PATH);
boost::filesystem::path p(buf0);
boost::filesystem::path dir = p.parent_path() / boost::filesystem::path("test");    
boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir);
```

Comment: Could you take a look at my last code. I'm trying to convert boost::filesystem::path to char * and join 2 chars then

Comment: If you want to alter the path I recommend using the filesystem api to do that. Here is a reference:https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html If you want to extract the path as a char* or wchar_t* you can use the ".c_str()" method. However TCHAR will need to be the same type for your program to compile. If not you'll need to convert. Do you need to make both multi-byte and widechar builds?

Comment: I actually want to launch file ShellExecute(NULL, NULL,dir, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW); But I can't, because it has to be char. Do you know how to launch file in boost? I didn't find any way. If I could put boost::filesystem::path in the middle it would be good.

Comment: I suggest using the wide char version: ShellExecuteW(...) then you can pass in the path ShellExecuteW(NULL, NULL, dir.wstring().c_str(), ...

Comment: My character set is Not Set

Comment: You can set the character set in the project properties page.

Comment: OMG!I really spent a lot of time on this. Thanks! I usually use Not Set to avoid red underlines on some texts in codes I have

Comment: @prako2 when using Win32 `A` and `W` functions directly, you don't need to worry about the project's character set anymore. It exists only to support `TCHAR` APIs, which you shouldn't be using anymore.